# Email Signature is creating attachments

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, email-signature

- I have several email addresses that I use in Outlook.
- My email signature includes some images.
- I have created an HTML page that I use to make sure my email signature is consistent across all of my computers (I copy it into the signature box).  Here it is:-
- https://www.member.buzz/content/resources/static/signatures/personal.html

Sometimes when I send emails to people with Gmail, my signature is converted into several attachments and is not displayed in the body of the email.  When they respond, the images continue to be attached - making the signature display incorrectly.

This does not seem to always happen like this - for instance, when I email my personal gmail from Outlook, the signature looks correct.

How can I make sure that my pretty HTML email signature is displayed correctly across all clients?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a problem with the recipient's Gmail account  configuration more than anything.

Comment: What is the configuration setting that they would need to change?

Comment: Any option that deals with automatically displaying images in an email.  Your email having attachments isn't that odd honestly

Comment: "How can I make sure that my pretty HTML email signature is displayed correctly across all clients?" You basically just give up on the idea that you can control how other people's email clients display your email, because you can't.